# Converting legacy string dates to dates

Tags: python

We have some legacy string dates that I need to convert to actual dates that can be used to perform some date logic. Converting to a date object isn't a problem if I knew what the format were! That is, some people wrote 'dd month yy', othes 'mon d, yyyy', etc.

So, I was wondering if anybody knew of a py module that attempts to guess date formats and rewrites them in a uniform way?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical approach is to define a list of formats (`strptime` formats, specifically), and try them in turn, until one works. As an example, see this recipe:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577135-parse-a-datetime-string-to-a-datetime-instance/

`strptime` accepts quite a number of formats. If you can enumerate all the possibilities you'll see, you should be able to hack together a variant of that recipe that'll do what you want.

Comment: Thank you Brian for the very quick response. :)

Answer (score 5):

Using [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil):

```
In [25]: import dateutil.parser as parser

In [26]: parser.parse('25 December 2010')
Out[26]: datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 25, 0, 0)

In [27]: parser.parse('Dec 25, 2010')
Out[27]: datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 25, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I like this and will have to remember it. But by the time I saw this, I had already ran the other script on my data and now it is done. :)