# Convert relative date string to absolute date

Tags: python, string, datetime, date

As input, I have a date string that can take three general formats:

a)  January 6, 2011
b)  4 days ago
c)  12 hours ago

I want the script to be able to recognize the format and call the appropriate function with the parameters.

So if a then convert_full_string("January 6, 2011")

if b then convert_days(4)

if c then convert_hours(12)

Once I recognize the format and able to call the appropriate function, it will be relatively easy.  I plan on using [dateutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528194/python-converting-legacy-string-dates-to-dates/4528300#4528300)

But I am not sure how to recognize the format.

Any suggestions with code samples much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [parsedatetime](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime), you could parse all three date formats into `datetime.datetime` objects without having to code the logic yourself:

```
import parsedatetime.parsedatetime as pdt
import parsedatetime.parsedatetime_consts as pdc
import datetime
c = pdc.Constants()
p = pdt.Calendar(c)
for text in ('january 6, 2011', '4 days ago', '12 hours ago'):
    date=datetime.datetime(*p.parse(text)[0][:6])
    # print(date.isoformat())
    # 2011-01-06T09:00:18
    # 2011-01-02T09:00:18
    # 2011-01-05T21:00:18
    print(date.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%S'))
    # 20110106T090208
    # 20110102T090208
    # 20110105T210208
```

Comment: Wow that simplifies things quite a bit!  Wasn't even aware of the library.  Any chance of getting the raw datetime object.  Ultimately, I want to just have the date time in the following formate :  20110106T083630

Comment: @Al Jepo: In the edited post above, `date` is a `datetime.datetime` object. Is that what you mean by "raw datetime object"? `date` has a `isoformat` method which comes close to your desired result, or you could use the `strftime` method to get it exactly.

Comment: thanks so much unutbu... you rock!  clearly well deserved 33.9K points!

Answer (score 0):

You can match with regular expressions:

```
import re
re.search(r".* [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4}", tomatch)
```

Similar with `[0-9]{1,2}` days ago, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'days' in userinput: 
    convert_days(userinput[:userinput.index('days')].strip())
elif 'hours' in userinput:
    convert_hours(userinput[:userinput.index('hours')].strip())
else:
    convert_full_string(userinput)
```

This assumes that when "days" or "hours" is contained in userinput, you always want the chars that came immediately before those two words.

Comment: Big assumption: "I'm counting the days until I can spend a few hours alone with my wife"

Comment: Well, OP wrote: 'As input, I have a date string that can take three general formats' ... No mention of poems or diary entries or so.